# Storing Larger (2MB) objects in Redis Azure

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, redis

I'm trying to use Redis in Azure for caching in my application. Each of my keys could be upwards of 2-4MB each. When I run my app against Redis on my local machine, all is great, however when running on Azure performance is terrible, retrieve of keys is often taking 8-10 seconds, its actually quicker for me to re-get this data from the original source than from the cache.

So I guess the first question is, are my keys too big? Am I just barking up the wrong tree altogther with using Redis?

If not, any ideas why it's so slow? The application is an Azure website, and the website and redis instance are in the same zone. I am using the stackexchange redis client and creating the multiplexer in the global.asax file as a singleton, to avoid re-creating this, the code for this is below:

**Global.asax:**

```
  redisConstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RedisCache"].ConnectionString;

            if (redisConstring != null)
            {
                if (RedisConnection == null || !RedisConnection.IsConnected)
                {
                    RedisConnection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(redisConstring);
                }
                RedisCacheDb = RedisConnection.GetDatabase();
                Application["RedisCache"] = RedisCacheDb;
            }
```

**Web API Controller:**

```
 IDatabase redisCache = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application["RedisCache"] as IDatabase;
            string cachedJson = redisCache.StringGet(id);
            if (cachedJson == null)
            {
                cachedJson=OutfitFactory.GetMembersJson(id);
                redisCache.StringSet(id, cachedJson, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15));


            }

                return OutfitFactory.GetMembersFromJson(cachedJson);
```

Comment: Yeah, that's not particularly small - it shouldn't be terrible, though; are you using local server memory as a cache *before* hitting redis?

Comment: @MarcGravell no at the moment I am only using redis (the main reason being I wanted to do some pre-loading of cache for popular queries) but I can do if needs be, prior to attempting to use Redis I was using local memory.

Comment: have you measured where the time is spent? is it bandwidth? or is it deserialization time?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's bandwidth, just accessing a value with the Redis desktop tool is slow as well. I've just switched it to use in memory caching and its a lot faster, not ideal though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the comments, it sounds like the issue is bandwidth... So: *use less bandwidth*. Ideas:

1. Use compression (ideally only if nontrivial size, etc)
2. Use a denser format

for reference, at SE we use gzip-compressed protobuf-net for packaging

Comment: Using Gzip and Protbuf got the size down to 8K and has made this much better, on par with in memory cache now. Thanks very much for the help!